# What is the advantage or benefit of using NSDictionary while parsing JSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I know we usually use `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` while we do serialization but I wonder are there any advantages if we prefer `NSDictionary`?

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Comment: It depends upon the response of the json...

Comment: NSDictionary provides key:value behavior which makes it easier to access required objects from dictionary. While in NSArray it is comparatively hard to acquire required object traversing through the JSON response.

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  JSON consists of *arrays* and *objects*.  These correspond very nicely to NSArrays and NSDictionarys.

Comment: (It's not a matter of "advantage".  The two quite simply cannot be interchanged.  Given the JSON you have no choice.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a matter of preference. The `JSONObjectWithData:` method returns an object of type `id`.

> A Foundation object from the JSON data in data, or nil if an error
>   occurs.

So it is not that you can choose whether you want an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`. In fact, you should always make a check to make sure that the returned object is of a type you expect.

Your code should look like:

```
NSError* error;
id JSONObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
                                                options:kNilOptions 
                                                  error:&error];

if ([JSONObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = (NSDictionary *)JSONObject;

    // Do your stuff.
}
```

Otherwise, you are risking a crash when `JSON` returned from the endpoint you are calling is not a dictionary anymore, but an array or anything that you don't expect.

Comment: OP should keep in mind that they have no control whatsoever what's in the JSON they receive. JSONObjectWithData: will return whatever is in the JSON data, not what the programmer _expects_ to be there.